# How to create draft pages with dependent elements in insert-only database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have an insert-only PostgreSQL database with a Book table, a Page table and an Element table.
Books can have multiple pages and pages can have multiple elements.
The database is insert-only because any time a page is modified, a new version of that page is created in a new record for auditing reasons.

```
-------------
Book
-------------
id [PK]

-------------
Page
-------------
id [PK]
book_id [FK]
version
created

-------------
Element
-------------
id [PK]
page_id [FK]
version
created
```

Currently, Element has a Foreign Key pointing to Page.id and Page has a Foreign Key pointing to Book.id.

A requirement is to have independent page drafts (versions) that can contain any number of elements. Every time a new page draft (version) is created, the new draft should be a clone of the previous version and it should contain all elements in the previous version. Elements can be added to or removed from a specific version of the Page, although Elements records are never deleted.

For scalibility reasons, I would avoid cloning all the elements together with the page, since the elements could be a very large number. I would also what to avoid many-to-many relationships between pages and elements.

I was thinking about replacing the Element.page_id FK with an Element.book_id FK so to have a single bucket of elements and pages more loosely coupled with each other. This way, when cloning a page, I wouldn't have to clone all the elements, but I would need a way to associate each element with a particular version of a Page.

Ideally, I should be able to retrieve a page version with all the elements associated to that version with a single SQL query.

I am still in a design/prototyping phase, so any aspect of the databse can potentially be changed to fulfill the requirements.

What could be the best way to associate Pages and Elements according to the requirements above? I hope the requirements are clear, if not, please ask any questions and I'll try to clarify.

Note: by "insert-only" database I mean a database where no record gets ever updated or deleted, only inserted. This is for auditing purposes so we can have a full history of any editing activity.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is using **Unary Relationship on Pages** (each Page has parent Page_id).

1. You can insert each new Pages with it's own Elements. (with null parent)
2. If any new versions of existing Pages coming, you can insert new Page with parent Page id.
3. There is no need to set Elements of parent Page to new Page. (the Page can retrieve them from parent Page)
4. If new version has it's specific Elements, you can set them to new coming Page.
5. and so on.

Note that, PostgreSQL has remarkable performances in recursive queries.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I think that if I want to update an Element in a child Page but belonging to a parent Page, I can just add a new Element to a child Page with same hash identifier but more recent `created` date. This way, if I want to query for all the elements of a child Page I can take Elements with distinct hashes and most recent `created` date.